# How to add Honeywell wireless thermostat to furnace with "add a wire" installed

Tags: electrical, hvac

I am trying to wire up from an older 4 wire RADIO CT30E thermostat to a smart wireless HONEYWELL RTH9580WF1013 thermostat. A post on the HONEYWELL site - or connected to it - suggested moving the green wire to the "c" common on the thermostat and then moving the green wire at the furnace block to the "C" block and thereby bringing the 24V power to the thermostat; tried that, didn't work. The furnace is a LENNOX G57-MP-36C-090-07 GAS. I will try to list the wires on the furnace block:

Y - Yellow (from AAW) / Red (from 2 wire red and black - in red casing #1)
W - Black from upstairs thermostat (from 4 wire bundle)
R - Plum color from AAW / R from upstairs thermostat bundle / R wire (from red and black - in red casing #2).
G - Black (from 2 wire red and black - in red casing #1) / Green from AAW
C - Black (from 2 wire red and black - in red casing #2) / Plum color from AAW

At AAW:
Green from upstairs 4 wire bundle wire nutted to blue wire from the AAW

At the upstairs thermostat (new Honeywell base)

```
LABEL   WIRE COLOR    BASE CONNECTOR
"C"     Green          "C" - Based on the original re-wire instructions marked as "C"
"RH"    Red            "R" - RH on the radio thermostat; no "RH" on Honeywell
"Y"     Yellow         "Y" - Same as on old radio thermostat
"W"     Black          "W" - Same as on old radio thermostat
```

Behind the Honeywell base:
Yellow and green wires from the Honeywell base (old radio installation wires) spade spliced together to blue section of wire and blue wire wire nutted to green wire coming out of the red encased 4 wire bundle in the wall.

I had photos but too big to load. Hope there is enough in the narrative to be clear. The text has been reformatted so it's not quite as clear as when I typed it in. Sorry.

Comment: I think if you can rewire your furnace you can resize a photo.   Help us help you.

Comment: Can you post your photos to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and then post a link to them here?

Comment: OK..it was my first time using the platform..obviously..but still learning how to do things..I'm 71 so not necessarily an excuse.  First..thanks to Frederic Shope for 'editing" my post and re-formatting it (?).  To jay613 - yes..I did work on that after the post and downloaded app to do that and did re-size the photos and save them.  That brings me to comment from ThreePhaseEel re posting of photos on imgur and posting link to them here; working on that; may have to come to you on how to do that.  I will see how things go.  Thanks again for the assists and still learning the protocols.

Comment: OK..think i have photos saved on IMGUR...i tried looking in FAQs for how to post links to photos but couldnt find anything on that.  How do you do that?  Thanks for support.

Comment: Just post the imjur link here. Someone will embed them for you & you can take a look at how it's done. Or, edit the question again and use the "Sun & mountain" icon to embed each image link.

Comment: Thanks for help @Freeman.  I have the "links" in IMGUR; I can't copy and paste them here; do you have to manually type them in?  How do I get them here.  I tried the "sun and mountain" approach and got one photo onto the post area; it asked for a description which I typed in; then, i tried going back to add the other four pictures but the post just seemed to add the new photo and the old one disappeared and there were a bunch of numbers and brackets before the post narrative which i guess are some kind of programming language...dont understand any of it.

Comment: I think as a new user, you're limited to one image per post (that limit goes away after you get some rep). Edit the "share" link directly from the imjur page into your question. It should automatically become a link, and someone will be able to embed them for you.

Comment: The only part that makes sense is *steal the G fan wire for your new C common* sure, that's fine, now you just can't call only the fan to circulate. Random colors nutted to w/e other colors - that's your problem to figure out. Tell me you have like, the C on the furnace goes to the C on the t-stat. Same with R and W. - It's letter to same letter... (and R or R[H] or R[C]: they all mean Red). - The t-stat needs C and R to function. W can call for heat. If you cross W and R/R[H] and the heat doesn't come on, you probably popped the 3 amp fuse. Don't screw w/ a t-stat while the furnace has power.

Comment: Get a length of t-stat wire and wire it directly to the furnace and hold the secret button down, *if* you're inclined to do so. If it works, then the furnace and t-stat work, and the only problem left is your spaghetti. *Help me with my spaghetti* deff needs pictures.

Comment: Many thanks to the various posters.  Yes..I did some further looking and disconnecting this morning and discovered at the Thermostat back that the original thermostat wire was a three wire not a four wire. So..rather than beat my head against a wall...I am simply going to go to the City and get two lengths of 5 wire thermostat wire ( one for the current install and one for the future - who knows how many wires some new "home control centre" might want ).  I'll just cut drywall out, strip the old three wire and ADD A WIRE out and wire new with the 5 wire from the thermostat to the furnace.